# merged months in datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using jquery ui datepicker,

1. Can I display and merge two months together?
2. Can I set the months sliding top(backward)-down(forward)?

This an example of what I need:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you read the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), and tell us ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `numberOfMonths` field you can specify more than one months to be shown at once. See a demo here : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars

You can set it like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [2,1]
});
```

And about showing it one below the other also there should be some field. Checkout it's documentation here : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I know this property very well and even using its array option. I asked if I can merge them both and not get them separated.